# In stripe update subscription plan without using customer portal

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments, stripes

In my application i am using our pricing table so that the customer can choose which plan he wants to upgrade to,
for upgrading the subscription i had done something like this:

modified_subscription = stripe.Subscription.modify(
subscription,
payment_behavior='default_incomplete',
items=[{'id': sub_id['data'][0]['items']['data'][0]['id'],
'price': price.id}],
collection_method="send_invoice",
proration_behavior='always_invoice',
days_until_due=1,
cancel_at=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=365),
)

here i had given  collection_method="send_invoice", which will invoice the customer when he wants to upgrade the subscription and days_until_due=1 is provided till when the customer can do the payment, but the issue i am facing is that i want the customer to first pay for the new subscription and then upgrade him to the new subscription.
can anyone help me with this so that i can proceed ?

How can I modify my subscription upgrade process to ensure that customers pay for the new subscription before being upgraded to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an one-off invoice for your customer, and only update the subscription when the invoice is paid successfully. You can also apply a coupon to the subscription and give them a discount for the amount that they already paid for the one-off invoice.

Comment: while creating the on-off invoice can we charge the prorated amount to the customer